# paint() does not get called in JLabel animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, jlabel

I want to have a bubbling effect - some image with score bubbling from bottom to up. Below is the complete code. The problem is that paint() never gets called by repaint(). I am not good at java awt or swing. Any reason?

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

  /**
   * The Bubble object for implementing some animations for each block of LOVE pieces
   */
    class Bubble extends JLabel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        boolean  isBubbling = false;

        int xpos;
        int ypos;
        float transparency;
        String text = "+100";
        GameSettings config;

        AlphaComposite transparency05=AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f);

        Bubble(int x, int y) {
            isBubbling=false;
            this.xpos = x;
            this.ypos = y;
        }

        void Bubbling() {
            isBubbling=true;
            for(int i=1;i<=50; i+=4) {
                System.out.println("Bubbling init");
              ypos -= (int)(7.2*i);
              transparency = transparency/2;
              setFont(new Font("arial, helvetica",Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC,i));
              repaint();
              try {Thread.sleep(15);} catch(Throwable e) {}
            }

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    for(int i=50;i>=0; i-=4) {
                        System.out.println("Bubbling run");
                      ypos -= (int)(7.2*i);
                      transparency = transparency/2;
                      setFont(new Font("arial, helvetica",Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC,i));
                      repaint();
                      try {Thread.sleep(15);} catch(Throwable e) {}
                    }
                    isBubbling=false;
                    repaint();
                }
            }.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g1) {
            super.paint(g1);

            System.out.println("Bubbling paint begin");
            if(isBubbling) {
                System.out.println("Bubbling paint");

              Graphics2D  g=(Graphics2D) g1;
              g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

              FontMetrics fm=g.getFontMetrics();
              Rectangle r = getBounds();

              int width=fm.stringWidth(text);
              int height=fm.getHeight()*4/5;
              int cx=g.getFont().getSize()/10;
              int x=(r.width-width)/2;
              int xx=fm.charWidth('i');

              //g.setComposite(transparency05);
              g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
              g.setColor(Color.red);
              //g.drawString(text,xpos*config.pieceWidth,ypos*config.pieceHeight);
              g.drawString(text,xpos,ypos);

              //Image img=Tetris.getResource().getImage(config.imagePath+config.imagePrefix+"heart"+config.imagePostfix);
              //g.drawImage(img,img.getWidth(null)+3,0,null);
              //g.drawImage(img,xpos*config.pieceWidth,ypos*config.pieceHeight,null);
            }
        }

        //for test
        static public void main(String[] args) {
            //Create and set up the window.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //Create and set up the content pane.
            JPanel newContentPane = new JPanel();
            newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
            Bubble bub = new Bubble(50, 50);
            newContentPane.add(bub);

            frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

            //Display the window.
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            bub.Bubbling();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Most likely, your `Bubble` has a preferred size of (0x0), hence the `FlowLayout` of the content pane will allocate a size of 0x0 to your label and therefore nothing is painted.

Comment: But aren't you blocking your EDT by calling `Thread.sleep(15)` inside your `Bubbling` method. Please learn [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and stick to them

Comment: @nIcEcOw No, is in another Thread.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet : Please do watch the first `for loop` inside the same method, `thread` creation comes after that, it appears to me :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw My bad, I did not see his first loop. But he is also in another Thread (the Main-Thread) (Bubbling method is only called once from the `main()`  method). I agree that this is very fragile and not well designed.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet : Too true, seems like EDT is absent from the very start. It's either the `main` thread or the thread created inside the `Bubbling()` method.

Comment: The values for `ypos` only seem to be positive once.  Everything else is drawn off-screen.  A little debugging would have shown this.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  That almost was, bar the missing `GameSettings` class - easily refactored to an `Object` for the demo. code.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. GuillaumePolet, with your guiding points, I get it working now. yes I admit the code is very fragile and not well designed. I am still working on refactoring the code to make it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many issues in your code, but the main reason why `paint()` is not invoked, is because your `Bubble` component has a size of 0 x 0. This is because you did not override `getPreferredSize()` to return an adequate value. Moreover, your `ypos` variable becomes negative in no time meaning that you don't have the time to see the animation.

Now, you should really consider taking care of the following other issues:

- Override rather `paintComponent` than `paint`
- Make sure that you never sleep on the EDT (here it does not happen because you are quite lucky)
- Start your UI from the EDT with a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` call.
- Why do you create another thread in your `Bubbling` method remains a mistery to me (either do it from the start, for the entire method, or don't do it at all)
- a `javax.swing.Timer` would be much more appropriate in your situation
- Follow java naming conventions (methods start with a lower-case letter)

Here is an update of your code (but I did not changed everything according the remarks above):

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * The Bubble object for implementing some animations for each block of LOVE pieces
 */
class Bubble extends JLabel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    boolean isBubbling = false;

    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    float transparency;
    String text = "+100";

    AlphaComposite transparency05 = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f);

    Bubble(int x, int y) {
        isBubbling = false;
        this.xpos = x;
        this.ypos = y;
    }

    void Bubbling() {
        isBubbling = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i += 4) {
            System.out.println("Bubbling init");
            ypos--;
            transparency = transparency / 2;
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, i));
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            }
        }

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 50; i >= 0; i -= 4) {
                    System.out.println("Bubbling run");
                    ypos--;
                    transparency = transparency / 2;
                    setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, i));
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                    }
                }
                isBubbling = false;
                repaint();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(180, 50);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
        super.paintComponent(g1);

        if (isBubbling) {
            System.out.println("Bubbling paint");

            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            Rectangle r = getBounds();

            int width = fm.stringWidth(text);
            int height = fm.getHeight() * 4 / 5;
            int cx = g.getFont().getSize() / 10;
            int x = (r.width - width) / 2;
            int xx = fm.charWidth('i');

            // g.setComposite(transparency05);
            // g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            // g.drawString(text,xpos*config.pieceWidth,ypos*config.pieceHeight);
            System.err.println(xpos + " " + ypos);
            g.drawString(text, xpos, ypos);

            // Image img=Tetris.getResource().getImage(config.imagePath+config.imagePrefix+"heart"+config.imagePostfix);
            // g.drawImage(img,img.getWidth(null)+3,0,null);
            // g.drawImage(img,xpos*config.pieceWidth,ypos*config.pieceHeight,null);
        }
    }

    // for test
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create and set up the content pane.
        JPanel newContentPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
        Bubble bub = new Bubble(50, 50);
        newContentPane.add(bub);

        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        bub.Bubbling();
    }

}
```

Comment: i never understand why override `getPreferredSize()` breaking liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @nachokk I would rather say that this is a question of splitting the responsabilities properly. There are 2 ways you can see this: 1. you use a `LayoutManager`, then it feels only natural to delegate the computation of the preferred size to that LM. 2. You don't use a `LayoutManager` (this is mainly the case when using custom painting), then only the component itself, or the custom painter, knows how much space it needs. In all cases, `setPreferredSize()` should be avoided and by overriding `getPreferredSize()` I ensure that nobody else will change the preferred size I have computed.

Comment: @nachokk : To be true, I always think, that overriding `getPreferredSize()` is a better option, than using `setXxXSize()` methods in many situations. Moreover, in many situations, `setXxXSize()` methods do not work, in the manner in which `getPreferredSize()` does. In many a situations `LayoutManager` will not give heed to calls like `setXxXSize()` though it mostly/always respects `getPreferredSize()` (though this is what is observed by me so far, so it can be my opinion) :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your label no Dimension. You can set with `setPreferredSize()`

```
public static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(70, 70);
    //in main method or you can override `getPreferredSize()`   
    Bubble bub = new Bubble(50, 50);
    bub.setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
```

Your are sleeping [The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). All gui stuff must be executed in that thread, instead of that take a look to [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Also you should override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()` for swing components. Read more in this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: `repaint()` is one of the few methods you can safely call outside the EDT

Comment: @nachokk : No need to feel sorry, we all commit mistakes one time or the other :-) These are just minute things which can slip past anyone on his/her's not so lucky day :-)